# In Safari, hovering over SVG elements causes a scrolled element to reset its scroll position?

Tags: html, css, svg, browser, safari

I have a [website](https://charge.js.org) that is exhibiting bizarre behavior that I don’t understand. I’m unable to tell if I’ve run into a bug or what I might be doing wrong.

The page has two elements, `nav` and `main` that each have `overflow-y: scroll` set. This is so they can be scrolled independently of one another. If I scroll the `main` element, and then hover over the pagination buttons at the bottom, the `main` element will jump back to the top (lose its scroll position). It also happens if I hover over the Octocat/GitHub symbol in the navigation on the right.

The common thread here is that the pagination buttons and the GitHub symbol on the right both have `svg` elements. If I get rid of the `svg` element the bug doesn’t happen. Also if I remove `overflow-y: scroll` from the `main` element the bug does not occur.

I’ve also noticed that the issue might be somehow related to having `height: 100%` set on the `<html>` tag. When it’s removed the issue no longer occurs, but unfortunately it can’t be removed otherwise the full width/height layout doesn’t work correctly.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, if it’s a bug in Safari, and/or how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: It turns out that this does appear to be a bug in Safari and it is fixed in Safari Technology Preview. So presumably it will roll out to Safari in the near future!

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=197189

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending hours and hours on this, the only way I could figure out how to fix it was to switch from CSS grid to flexbox. ‍♂️

This is the [diff that fixed it](https://github.com/brandonweiss/charge/commit/b932695c92e31ba894a0960ef96cf48aa6900dbf), if you’re curious.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by adding the following to `body` where your grid rules are defined. Sadly, I have no idea why this solves the issue.

```css
body {
  …
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea why this fixes it either, but I’ll happily take this workaround in the meantime! ❤️

Comment: Damn, apparently this doesn’t completely fix it. It does seem to fix it in a desktop browser, but for some reason on mobile iOS the problem still occurs. 

Comment: Actually, now I can’t even get the initial fix to work on desktop.  It definitely seemed to work initially…

Comment: @BrandonWeiss I can't reproduce it on mobile or desktop Safari.

Comment: The workaround seems to work for the GitHub SVG in the nav on the right, but seems to not work for the pagination buttons. When you mouseover the pagination buttons everything is fine?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug related to safari version 12.1, which is fixed in Safari Technological Preview. 
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=197189

However as a workaround in the mean time. 
Can you try 
overflow-x:hidden, overflow-y: scroll,
height between 50 to 95vh for the specific container depending on your surrounding elements. This is going to have minimal safari jump on hover and probably empty space at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Even after Safari bug is fixed, seems that the bug still occurs on some other scenario. I successfully reproduced a similar behavior on Fluent UI dropdown: https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/23668

The workaround in my case was to change dropdown item height from "auto" to "100%".